# construction proplem-solved pending proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

ABC is a right triangle and E a point in the plane. Construct with compass and ruler the equilateral triangle EDF with  D and F lying in the sides of ABC.

Comment: There must be something more to it. If $E $ is **any** point then this may be impossible. If E is far away enough then D and F can't be on the sides of ABC

Comment: Yes, after solving it you might add that if E is too far there has no solution, but ther IS a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a complete new version.**

We have to assume that E is outside of ABC and within range. Let ABC be right-angled at B.

[image]

Draw the equilateral triangle PBE.

Construct the circum-circle PBE cutting BC at X.

PX will cut AC at D.

Construct the circle (centered at E with ED as radius) cutting BC at F.

This is because if $\triangle PED \cong \triangle BEF, \angle DEF = \angle PEB = 60^0$

Comment: Why, except the  pending proof.. to me it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I did what you told me @Mick but as you can see the triangle is not equilateral

Comment: Did you construct the circles?

Comment: Yes, the perpendicular bisector

Comment: did not make a full use of the right angle part and I will delete my post in a short while. I will upload a better solution if I can find one.

Comment: Forget the old version and see the new one.

Comment: you are so kind, thank you!